# Intersect and mutate

Tags: dplyr

I have two tibbles `a` and `b`.

I would like to find the common values across both tibbles and then mutate tibble `a` to signify a match.

```
library(tidyverse)

a<-as_tibble(c("cat", "dog", "bird"))
b<-as_tibble(c("sheep", "cow", "dog", "pig", "cat", "mouse"))

dplyr::intersect(a, b)
```

Expected output:

```
  value common
  <chr> <dbl>
1 cat     1
2 dog     1
3 bird    0
```

The final `mutate` stafge is eluding me, any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to just check if there's commonality in a mutate:

```
a %>%
  mutate(common = ifelse(value %in% b$value))
```

Or in a join:

```
inner_join(
  x = a,
  y = b %>% mutate(common = 1),
  by = "value") %>%
replace_na(list(common = 0))
```

With dplyr, working with one tibble is much easier than multiples so you first step should be getting them together, not making a new one. :) I don't think intersect is the right tool for the job in this case. However, if you need to actually intersect for whatever reason, you can just use either of the above techniques to annotate/join to your tibble a.

(Also, you'll probably see a warning about using as_tibble on vectors, so you should switch to either tibble() or enframe() to make your code more future-proof.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s) GenesRus. Fully agree with your statement about getting the df's together, rather than creating new ones. I'll have a think about the best way of doing this for my data as there are several nuances which I need to consider in more detail.

Comment: I'm partial to nested (legacy) columns that wrapped values in lists. Say you need to create an all by all, you can do something like: 
`tibble(test = seq(1,10)) %>% mutate(nest = list(LETTERS[1:4])) %>% unnest_legacy()`
And then you can impose conditional filters if you need more than what a join could do. You can also use purrr::map or map2 to dig into nested tibbles if you need to bring along more columns. Anyway, that's been useful in my workflow, which resembled yours initially. It's not the most memory efficient, but it's fine for all but the largest of datasets on modern computers.